# Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.ts

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I got error in visual studio code ->

Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.ts

I dont know reaseon but check my code:

```
  trainingPlanResponse: any[] = [];


  this.service.postToGetData(model).subscribe(
    data => {
      // this.trainingPlanResponse.push(data);
      this.trainingPlanResponse = data; // HERE IS ERROR!!!
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err) 
    }
  )
```

When i set to

```
trainingPlanResponse: any;
```

This work but I need to set in html

```
        <div *ngIf="trainingPlanResponse.length > 0">
            response 
        </div>
```

Important: I don't have model interface for this!

Comment: try `this.trainingPlanResponse = data as any[];`

Comment: Can you show postToGetData code?

Comment: yes this is work but i want to know why error ? What happened? Can i set it without interface ?

Comment: @VladimirBozhinovski it is no important 
It is const modelPost = { id: thisi , name: this.name ...}

Comment: Try something like this -> this.trainingPlanResponse = data || []

Answer (score 1):

A response from an http request returns an Observable of type `Object`

**Example**

Lets say you have a function `postToGetData()`

```js
postToGetData() {
  return this.httpClient.get('my-url')
}
```

`Typescript` will infer the function `postToGetData` to return an `Observable<Object>`

The easiest solution to this is to simply use **type casting** like below

```js
postToGetData() {
  return this.httpClient.get<any[]>('my-url')
}
```

The above will infer `postToGetData` to return `any[]`

You may also define the return type of the function as `any[]`

```js
postToGetData(): any[] {
  return this.httpClient.get('my-url').pipe(map(items => items as any[]))
}
```